# Image processing library for Android?

Tags: android, image-processing

A friend who works in the medical profession asked me to try and write a small application for Android that could take a picture, analyze it in terms of colors and size so we know how it evolved since the last snapshot, and make recommendations based on that evolution.

I'm only getting started with Android, and was wondering if someone knew of a good library that could do this and save development time.

Answer (score 18):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) (for Open Computer Vision) is a C++ image processing library widely used by researchers in image processing, computer vision, robotics... (at least for the ones who don't use matlab). It does officially support Android, and it is actively developed.

Furthermore, it has a lot of advanced functions that you can use later if you need it.

Comment: Either there's a dearth of libraries to analyze pictures, or googling for "smartphone photo analysis library" just isn't right. I need to ask experts about what the options are to write an application, what the leaders are in the field, how much their library costs, etc.

Comment: Apparently, the right search words are "image processing library". I guess they are usually written in C/C++ so are available for both Android and iPhone.

Comment: To analyse an image, you will apply some signal or image processing algorithms to it. So, yes, the search item is "image processing library". OpenCV also comes with some NEON optimization, which can be useful for ARM-based devices (i.e. most of Android devices).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll keep searching with "image processing" keywords.

Comment: OpenCv prompts for a doenload for OpenCV manager...So include OpenCV iff You can tolerate this in your app

Answer (score 13):

I found [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) better for Android since it exports Java API. It also supports other image processing libraries.

Answer (score 6):

You might look into Imagemagick. It has a couple Android ports (see https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick for one of the two I know of) and I am pretty sure I read that it has support for doing what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Use JavaCV, is a Wrapper for OpenCV. JavaCV Contains all most all the functions that OpenCV contains. Although JavaCV haven't any rich documentation you can use OpenCV documentation to find the functions that you can use for your project. JavaCV has same method signature (not for all) as OpenCV.

- [JavaCV HomePage - Download and How to setup on Android
  environment(Eclipse)](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)
- [OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/)

Comment: It seems this library is quite large (6.4MB for Android), and it has the "GNU GPL v2" license. Is it ok to modify its code so that I could remove most of it? It's not quite making more features, but rather removing them. I only need a very basic set of features from it (for example rotating, scaling, cropping, but not filtering and other similar stuff...). Also, does this library do the decoding inside it , or on the Java side (using BitmapFactory) ? I hope all memory usage is on the "JNI world", or it could cause OOM...

Answer (score 1):

I found JHLabs libary, which is very easy to use and basic image processing filters to be used.
https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/ -> this link is not found

https://github.com/finebyte/android-jhlabs

Comment: I am using jhlabs in one of my application.

Comment: where is the tutorial?

Comment: There are no tutorials available. You have to research on it by using pre-define methods in the library.