# Android device slow calculation

Tags: android, math, optimization

In my app I'm loading an image then using standard *ColorUtils* for transforming it into different colour space pixel by pixel with several **>** or **<** conditions. After all conditions I collect resulting pixel value to re-create bitmap. There are no lags, yet it takes a lot of time (more than a minute) to calculate a new bitmap for 80x600 image whilst it is supposed to work with greater images. Is there any way to speed up these caluclations? Is caclulation limited by default, e.g. only one CPU? How can I use all of computational capabilities of a device? How to optimize calculation?

Comment: you should edit the question to include a [simplified version of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem, also tag the question with the actual language you're implementing this in

Answer (score 0):

I think that [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466102/image-processing-library-for-android) is exactly what you need. At least try to perform any heavy computations with C++ via JNI.